# Track google+ shares in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-plus, share, analytics

I installed google analytics for my site and been tracking all social networks, as far as i know google+ activities will be tracked by default. I got succeeded in tracking all social networks, but my client wants to show google+ "Share" also, right now it is tracking only google+ "+1". Please help me how to track google+ "Share".

Note : i am using ga.js not analytics.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to see clicks on the share button? Cause you can do that with event tracking.

Here is all the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Also here is a [good guide on Google+ tracking](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/googleplus) in GA by one of Google's GA Advocate

Comment: Hi NicoM, Thanks for your reply.

Event tracking says only how to track videos, downloads and plays but i need to track how many people shared my page via google+.

Thanks

Comment: Hi gkarthikeyanmca, yes event tracking can track videos and DL's but it can basically do anything track anything on the page. It can track the interaction with g+ wigets that you have. However, if someone copies the site URL and goes to G+ and shares, it wont track that. Is the G+ account a business page? They just came out with some basic stats for them but I havent seen the ability to connect them yet. So I guess they are rolling them out slowly.  Hope that helps! source: http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2330146/Google-Pages-Dashboards-Now-Link-to-Google-Analytics

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, by reading many articles and google docs i concluded that tracking google+ shares is not possible or may be deprecated by google itself.